# Nvidia 3D Vision option is missing (driver 430+)

Tags: stereo-3d, nvidia-geforce-experience

I am used to playing 3D Games on my 3D TV compatible projector, but I no longer see the option in the Nvidia control panel when I plug it in via the HDMI port on my computer. I am running a GTX 1050Ti.

Is there no longer a way to use NVidia 3D Vision?

Comment: [Comments Deleted] - This situation appears to be resolved now, but just a friendly reminder to all commenters that participation on Arqade should abide by the [Code of Conduct](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/conduct) :-).

Answer (score -1):

[418 was the last driver to support 3D vision for all games.](https://www.engadget.com/2019/03/11/nvidia-ends-3d-vision-support/)

You can downgrade your driver by installing the 3D vision driver for free from Nvidia Driver version 418

- [Official Link](https://us.download.nvidia.com/Windows/418.91/418.91-desktop-win10-64bit-international-whql.exe)
- [Mirror](https://www.dropbox.com/s/8bpq586srqi4ft0/418.91-desktop-win10-64bit-international-whql.exe?dl=0)